# How can I disable the mouse wheel for a TextArea without disabling the entire control?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols

I'm using a `TextArea` to display multi-line text with embedded `<IMG ...>` tags in the delegate for a `ListView`. I have it set to read-only (and not disabled) because I need hyperlinks in the text to be clickable so I need to make use of its `onLinkActivated` event handler. This is normally something that would call for a `Label` (which does not handle mouse wheel events), but a `Label` does not render line-breaks correctly when the text includes `<IMG ...>` tags in the HTML.

The problem I'm having is that a `TextArea` handles mouse wheel events even when it is read-only, so if the cursor happens to be over one of the visible `TextArea` controls, the `ListView` will not respond to mouse wheel events (and so it does not scroll). In other words, the `TextArea` is capturing the mouse wheel events and I want it to not do this.

I see in the docs that controls have a `wheelEnabled:` property, but `TextArea` does not seem to support this.

**Update:** here is a minimum code sample that demonstrates the problem:

```
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4 as Controls

Rectangle {

    id: test

    color: "white"
    width: 300
    anchors {
        left: parent.left
        top: parent.top
        bottom: parent.bottom
    }

    Controls.ScrollView {

        id: _scrollview

        anchors.fill: parent

        ListView {
            anchors.fill: parent
            model: 100

            delegate: Rectangle {
                id: tableRow
                width: test.width
                height: 50
                color: "yellow"

                TextArea {
                    width: test.width / 2
                    height: tableRow.height
                    readOnly: true
                    text: "Row # " + index
                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

If you hold the mouse cursor over the right side of this listview (i.e. not over the `TextArea` control in the row), the mouse wheel works as expected. But if you hold the mouse cursor over the `TextArea` in any of the rows, the `ListView` will not scroll with the mouse wheel (because the readOnly `TextView` is capturing the events).

Comment: this is a lot of code to re-code and reproduce, it'd be helpful if you can post a minimal working example. If I understood you corrently, I suggest using a 1 liner text input and not `TextArea`. Since it's read-only, use `Label` or r/o `TextInput`

Comment: @bardao Well, the text I need to display is multi-line and includes HTML. I was previously using a `Label` here, but it does not handle word-wrapping correctly when the HTML includes `<IMG ...>` tags (this may be a since-fixed Qt bug, since I am stuck using Qt 5.6).

Comment: @MusiGenesis You should point this out in your question so that other users do not give you that kind of alternative solutions :-)

Comment: would this work for you then? `flickableItem.enabled: false` property of `TextArea`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually pretty easy, too bad I wasted the bounty. All this requires is a `MouseArea` positioned over the `TextArea` like so:

```
MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: txtTester
    onPressed: {
        mouse.accepted = false
    }
    onReleased: {
        mouse.accepted = false
    }

    property int scrollValue: 15
    onWheel: {
        if (wheel.angleDelta.y < 0) {
            //make sure not to scroll too far
            if (!_scrollview.flickableItem.atYEnd)
                _scrollview.flickableItem.contentY += scrollValue
        }
        else {
            //make sure not to scroll too far
            if (!_scrollview.flickableItem.atYBeginning)
                _scrollview.flickableItem.contentY -= scrollValue
        }
    }
}
```

This ignores press and release events so clicking on hyperlinks in the `TextArea` still works, but it intercepts mouse wheel events and applies them to moving the `ScrollView` as if the TextArea were not there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 200

    TextArea {
        id: text
        anchors.fill: parent

        text: "Current\ntext\n\\to\nmove\ndown\ndown\ndown
               \ndown\ndown\ndown\ndown\ndown\ndown\ndown"

        flickableItem.interactive: false
    }
}
```

`TextArea` has `flickableItem.enabled` property. Since you're stuck with !t 5.6 this should work for you.

EDIT: changed to `flickableItem.interactive` instead.

Comment: Well, this does prevent the TextArea from capturing the mouse wheel event, but it also prevents the `onLinkActivated` handler from firing. It's effectively equivalent to setting the TextArea's enabled to false (it may be literally equivalent too, I dunno). My problem is I specifically need to ignore the mouse wheel but not ignore the clicks.

Comment: you're right I just thought about it, the `flickableItem` is actually the `TextArea`  :'D well that was fun

Comment: @MusiGenesis how about `flickableItem.interactive: false `

Comment: you can basically access all the `Flickable` properties. check here http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flickable.html see if any of those can help you solve the issue